# in C/C++, it is going to work when two function has same name, one end up call another

Tags: c++, c

I run into this problem, function F need to call function A, and function A  call a function from a third party which happen to have the same name as F.

Example:

```
    sendData()
    {
      ...
        socket(p1, p2, p3) // intention is to call version 1 
    }


    socket(p, p2, p3)     // this is version 1
    {
      ...
       xScoket(...);
       ...
    }

    xSocket(...)          // in separate file
   {
      ...
      socket(p1, p2, p3);  // intention is to call version 2 
                           // from third party
     }

    socket(...)    // this is version 2 from third party in separate file
   {
      ...
    }
```

I thought about using namespace, but then it think the name space is used to define two version of functions but not one calling another one. AM I right?

I thought about using #define as following for version 1, and hope the preprocessor will replace the version 1 socket with socketUnique, to avoid compiler/linker complains the duplicated error. But when I run a test, it does not work - the debug jump around with no sense.  So, I thought again, the #define could also replace the version 2 ( from a third party code ) too.

```
     #define socket socketUnique
```

So, I post this question here, and hope to hear some advise - either doable with solution, or not possible.

Thanks

Comment: C doesn't have namespaces. Please be clear about which language you expect an answer for.

Comment: 1. there is a difference if the 3rd party is in static/shared lib or in DLL. you need to be more specific. 2. you better put the `#define socket socketUnique`  after the `#include 3rdparty.h` but no way your macro is changing an already compiled code.

Comment: Downvote because you are not specifying which language this is about even though the answer will be vastly different for C and C++. Don't waste out time, tell us what language you use.

Comment: Sorry that, I was not say clearly - this is the first time I am using this website..  I am working on a embedded project using C/C++ code.  The code I am writing is in C.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are in separate files (and do not need to be called from other source-files), then the simplest solution is to make the function `static` in at least one of the two places.

If you need to call the function from multiple source files (and thus `static` doesn't work), I would rename "your" function(s), rather than rely on macros - using macros will make the code quite hard to read and it's definitely going to play havoc with any "source navigation tools" (cscope, etc)

Comment: Per the question, the one of the functions calls the other function with the same name.   Will not work in C.  Will work in C++, IF the functions have different 'signatures'.

Comment: Sorry that, I was not say clearly - this is the first time I am using this website..      I am working on a embedded project using C/C++ code.  The code I am writing is in C...   All functions has to be visible by others. - the third party function  ( version 2 from vendor ), the xSocket is implemented by another group and to be used by me.  The function (version 1 ) I am writing has to be public as it will be used by others application. I have to say, the whole thing is crazy - too many layers, but this is the policy set for me, I can not rename the Function I am implementing....